# Understanding the binary format of the Tensorflow V2 checkpoint .index files.

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the binary format of the .index file that is produced when saving a V2 checkpoint. I.e the following files are produced:

variables.index
variables.data-00000-of-00001

Looking at the data in the .index I can see that it contains BundleEntryProto seemingly paired with string names of the variable tensor.
However it's not a simple serialised list of BundleEntryProto, and the strings seem to have some partial delta compression i.e the first listing would be

"conv_block/batch_normalization/beta"
but the next name should be 
"conv_block/batch_normalization/gamma"
instead stored in the file is simply 
"gamma"

It also seems the file starts with 00 00, which isn't valid as a field/wire element, so presumably the file has some other container around it.

Any advice on what this container may be, or pointers on how to read this data file without using the Tensorflow API?